# How to iterate distance calculation for different vehicles from coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am new to coding and need help developing a Time Space Diagram (TSD) from a CSV file which I got from a VISSIM simulation as a result.

A general TSD looks like this: [TSD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2GIk.png) and I have a CSV which looks like this:
[CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iBhj.png).

I want to take "VEHICLE:SIMSEC" which represent the simulation time which I want it represented as the X axis on TSD, "NO" which represent the vehicle number (there are 185 different vehicles and I want to plot all 185 of them on the plot) as each of the line represented on TSD, "COORDFRONTX" which is the x coordinate of the simulation, and "COORDFRONTY" which is the y coordinate of the simulation as positions which would be the y axis on TSD.

I have tried the following code but did not get the result I want.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as mp

# take data
data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\hk385\Desktop\VISSIM_DATA_CSV.csv")

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["VEHICLE:SIMSEC", "NO", "DISTTRAVTOT"])

# plot the dataframe
df.plot(x="NO", y=["DISTTRAVTOT"], kind="scatter")

# print bar graph
mp.show()
```

The plot came out to be uninterpretable as there were too many dots. The diagram looks like this: [Time Space Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sma5I.png). So would you be able to help me or guide me to get a TSD from the CSV I have?

Suggestion made by mitoRibo,
The top 20 rows of the csv is the following:
VEHICLE:SIMSEC,NO,LANE\LINK\NO,LANE\INDEX,POS,POSLAT,COORDFRONTX,COORDFRONTY,COORDREARX,COORDREARY,DISTTRAVTOT
5.9,1,1,1,2.51,0.5,-1.259,-3.518,-4.85,-1.319,8.42
6.0,1,1,1,10.94,0.5,0.932,-4.86,-2.659,-2.661,16.86
6.1,1,1,1,19.37,0.5,3.125,-6.203,-0.466,-4.004,25.29
6.2,1,1,1,27.82,0.5,5.319,-7.547,1.728,-5.348,33.73
6.3,1,1,1,36.26,0.5,7.515,-8.892,3.924,-6.693,42.18
6.4,1,1,1,44.72,0.5,9.713,-10.238,6.122,-8.039,50.64
6.5,1,1,1,53.18,0.5,11.912,-11.585,8.321,-9.386,59.1
6.6,1,1,1,61.65,0.5,14.112,-12.933,10.521,-10.734,67.56
6.7,1,1,1,70.12,0.5,16.314,-14.282,12.724,-12.082,76.04
6.8,1,1,1,78.6,0.5,18.518,-15.632,14.927,-13.432,84.51
6.9,1,1,1,87.08,0.5,20.723,-16.982,17.132,-14.783,93.0
7.0,1,1,1,95.57,0.5,22.93,-18.334,19.339,-16.135,101.49
7.1,1,1,1,104.07,0.5,25.138,-19.687,21.547,-17.487,109.99
7.2,1,1,1,112.57,0.5,27.348,-21.04,23.757,-18.841,118.49
7.3,1,1,1,121.08,0.5,29.56,-22.395,25.969,-20.195,127.0
7.4,1,1,1,129.59,0.5,31.773,-23.75,28.182,-21.551,135.51
7.5,1,1,1,138.11,0.5,33.987,-25.107,30.396,-22.907,144.03
7.6,1,1,1,146.64,0.5,36.203,-26.464,32.612,-24.264,152.56
7.7,1,1,1,155.17,0.5,38.421,-27.822,34.83,-25.623,161.09

Thank you.

Comment: hi, can you please edit your question to include `df.head(20).to_dict(orient='list')`. This will make it easy for people answering your question to make the df themselves and try different solutions. Or just paste your text into your question. It is hard to work from an image. I'm guessing a solution will be to `groupby` `NO` and iterate plotting over the same figure

Comment: Thank you @mitoRibo. I have listed the top 20 rows of the CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can groupby and iterate through different vehicles, adding each one to your plot. I changed your example data so there were 2 different vehicles.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
VEHICLE:SIMSEC,NO,LANE_LINK_NO,LANE_INDEX,POS,POSLAT,COORDFRONTX,COORDFRONTY,COORDREARX,COORDREARY,DISTTRAVTOT
5.9,1,1,1,2.51,0.5,-1.259,-3.518,-4.85,-1.319,0
6.0,1,1,1,10.94,0.5,0.932,-4.86,-2.659,-2.661,16.86
6.1,1,1,1,19.37,0.5,3.125,-6.203,-0.466,-4.004,25.29
6.2,1,1,1,27.82,0.5,5.319,-7.547,1.728,-5.348,33.73
6.3,1,1,1,36.26,0.5,7.515,-8.892,3.924,-6.693,42.18
6.4,1,1,1,44.72,0.5,9.713,-10.238,6.122,-8.039,50.64
6.5,1,1,1,53.18,0.5,11.912,-11.585,8.321,-9.386,59.1
6.6,1,1,1,61.65,0.5,14.112,-12.933,10.521,-10.734,67.56
6.7,1,1,1,70.12,0.5,16.314,-14.282,12.724,-12.082,76.04
6.8,1,1,1,78.6,0.5,18.518,-15.632,14.927,-13.432,84.51
6.9,1,1,1,87.08,0.5,20.723,-16.982,17.132,-14.783,90
6.0,2,1,1,95.57,0.5,22.93,-18.334,19.339,-16.135,0
6.1,2,1,1,104.07,0.5,25.138,-19.687,21.547,-17.487,30
6.2,2,1,1,112.57,0.5,27.348,-21.04,23.757,-18.841,40
6.3,2,1,1,121.08,0.5,29.56,-22.395,25.969,-20.195,50
6.4,2,1,1,129.59,0.5,31.773,-23.75,28.182,-21.551,60
6.5,2,1,1,138.11,0.5,33.987,-25.107,30.396,-22.907,70
6.6,2,1,1,146.64,0.5,36.203,-26.464,32.612,-24.264,80
6.7,2,1,1,155.17,0.5,38.421,-27.822,34.83,-25.623,90
"""),sep=',')

fig = plt.figure()

#Iterate through each vehicle, adding it to the plot
for vehicle_no,vehicle_df in df.groupby('NO'):
    plt.plot(vehicle_df['VEHICLE:SIMSEC'],vehicle_df['DISTTRAVTOT'], label=vehicle_no)
    
plt.legend() #comment this out if you don't want a legned
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind could you please try this.

```
mp.scatter(x="NO", y=["DISTTRAVTOT"])
```

If still not work please attach your data for me to test from my side.

Comment: [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) | [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)